# QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded

Tags: drivers, mysql, qt

I lost a lot of time to solve the problem of connection with my database in Qt5 program,the OS is Ubuntu-18.04
, please help me

I have the error:

QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QPSQL QPSQL7
Failed to connect.

Comment: Did you install a MySQL library for this program/environment?  (`libqt4-sql-mysql` for Qt4, `libqt5sql5-mysql` for Qt5 for instance)  It almost looks like you didn't (it has SQLite and PostgreSQL support but not MySQL libs installed)